# Can I pass variable values to Python script from PythonOperator in Airflow using op_args or op_kwargs?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

From airflow DAG can I pass variable values as arguments to the python script using `op_args` or `op_kwargs`. In my airflow, Dag is importing my script as `from scripts import my_script` my python operator looks like this

```
PythonOperator(
    task_id='xxxxxx',
    python_callable=my_script.main,
    op_args=[bucket_name, prefix, source_blob_name, dest_bucket_name],
    dag=dag,
    trigger_rule='all_success'
)
```

I declared my variables in Airflow.  I could  be able to call my values `bucket_name=Variable.get('bucket_name')` here I want pass the value of **bucket_name** to my variable in Python script is that possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PythonOperator `op_args`, `op_kwargs`, `templates_dict` are [templated fields](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/27ded333a9cb5452541bd4bd362f18c03b29cfeb/airflow/operators/python.py#L124).

So you can do :

```
PythonOperator(
    ...,
    op_args=['{{ var.value.bucket_name }}'],
    python_callable=my_script.main
)
```

Then your Python callable would be:

```
def main(*op_args):
    bucket_name = op_args[0]
```

You can also use `op_kwargs` / `templates_dict`:

```
PythonOperator(
    ...,
    templates_dict={'bucket_name', '{{ var.value.bucket_name }}'},
    python_callable=my_script.main
)
```

Then your Python callable would be:

```
def main(bucket_name, **context):
    ...
```

But there is no need to do either of them.
There is no reason to pass argument that you can access directly with in your Python callable.

You can just do:

```
from airflow.models.variable import Variable
def main(**context):
    bucket_name = Variable.get('bucket_name')
```

This is perfectly safe since `main` is called only when `PythonOperator` is executed.

Comment: ops_args make sense to use ,  wondering  how can i create placeholder for  variables in my python script i have variables declared as  bucket_name = 'XXX', prefix = 'XXX', source_blob_name = 'XXX', dest_bucket_name = 'XXX' should i  declared them  something like bucket_name = %s , prefix = %s

Comment: That is a matter of preference... You can choose the `op_kwargs` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use params inside your PythonOperator like this:

```py
PythonOperator(
...
params={"bucket_name": bucket_name, "key": value}
...
)
```

And retrieve it:

```py
def main(**kwargs):
 bucket_name = kwargs.get("bucket_name")
...
```

Comment: my variable declarations  are  not inside main(),  am believing I need to create a placeholder for my variables first in python script , can i do something like this bucket_name = %s  ?

Comment: You could format it with f strings